# Discrepancy in computations

Tags: c#, sql-server, computation

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_LensThickCalcAC] (@sph as DECIMAL(9,2),
                              @cyl as DECIMAL(9,2),
                              @ri as DECIMAL(9,2),
                              @bc as DECIMAL(9,2), 
                              @dia as SMALLINT,
                              @ct as DECIMAL(9,2),
                              @axs as SMALLINT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @dR2S DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @dR2SC DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @dSizeA DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @dSizeB DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @dSizeC DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @dSizeB_S FLOAT
DECLARE @dSizeB_SC FLOAT
DECLARE @dThickness DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @dAxs DECIMAL(9,2)

DECLARE  @dESizeB_S FLOAT
DECLARE  @dESizeB_SC FLOAT
DECLARE  @dDiffSC FLOAT

DECLARE @dR1 DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @dESizeD FLOAT
DECLARE @dSizeD DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @adjThick DECIMAL(9,2)
DECLARE @finalThick DECIMAL(9,2)

IF(@AXS > 0) 
   BEGIN
    IF (@AXS >= 180)
       BEGIN 
         SET @dAxs = @AXS - 90
       END
    ELSE 
       BEGIN 
         SET @dAxs = @AXS
       END 
    END
ELSE
   BEGIN 
     SET @dAxs = @AXS
   END 

SET @dR2S = ((@RI - 1.0) * 1000) / (@BC - @Sph)


SET @dDiffSC = @BC - (@Sph + @Cyl)

IF @dDiffSC = 0 
  BEGIN 
    SET @dDiffSC = @BC
  END 

SET @dR2SC = ((@RI - 1.0) * 1000) / (@dDiffSC)

SET @dESizeB_S = POWER(@dR2S,2) - POWER(@DIA /2,2)
SET @dESizeB_SC = POWER(@dR2SC,2) - POWER(@DIA /2,2)

SET @dSizeB_S = @dR2S - Sqrt(@dESizeB_S)
SET @dSizeB_SC = @dR2SC - Sqrt(@dESizeB_SC)
SET @dSizeA = @CT

IF @dSizeB_S > @dSizeB_SC
   BEGIN 
     SET @dSizeB = @dSizeB_S
   END 
ELSE 
   BEGIN 
     SET @dSizeB = @dSizeB_SC
   END 

SET @dSizeC = @dSizeA + @dSizeB

SET @dR1 = (@RI - 1.0) * 1000 / (@BC)
SET @dESizeD = POWER(@dR1,2) - POWER(@DIA /2,2)

IF @dR1 > @dR2S
    BEGIN
        SET @dSizeD = @dR1 - sqrt(@dESizeD)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @dSizeD = @dSizeB
    END

SET @adjThick = @dSizeC - @dSizeD

IF @dSizeD > 3.50
    BEGIN
        SET @dSizeD = @dSizeD - 3.50
        SET @finalThick = @adjThick + @dSizeD + 1.50
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @finalThick =  @adjThick + 1.50
    END

RETURN @finalThick

END
```

From the stored SQL function above, trying I derive a  simple C# app from it.

Product:

```
public float calc2(decimal sph, decimal cyl, decimal bc, decimal dia, decimal ct, decimal Axs)
        {
```

`decimal ri = 1.74M, dAxis, dR2S, dR2SC, dR1;
        decimal dDiffSC, dSizeB_S, dSizeB_SC, dESizeD, dESizeB_S, dESizeB_SC;
        decimal dSizeA, dSizeB, dSizeC, dSizeD;
        decimal adjthick;
        float finaloutput;
        dAxis = Axs > 0 ? (Axs >= 180 ? Math.Round(Axs - 90,2) : Math.Round(Axs,2)) : Math.Round(Axs,2);

        dR2S = Math.Round((((Math.Round(ri, 2) - 1.0M) * 1000)/(bc - sph)),2);

        dDiffSC = bc - (sph + cyl);
        dDiffSC = dDiffSC == 0 ? bc : dDiffSC;

        dR2SC = Math.Round((((Math.Round(ri, 2) - 1.0M) * 1000) / (dDiffSC)),2);

        dESizeB_S = dPow(dR2S, 2M) - dPow((dia/2), 2M);
        dESizeB_SC = dPow(dR2SC, 2M) - dPow((dia/2), 2M);

        dSizeB_S = dR2S - (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)dESizeB_S);
        dSizeB_SC = dR2SC - (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)dESizeB_SC);
        dSizeA = Math.Round(ct, 2);

        dSizeB = dSizeB_S > dSizeB_SC ? Math.Round(dSizeB_S,2) : Math.Round(dSizeB_SC,2);

        dSizeC = Math.Round((dSizeA + dSizeB),2);

        dR1 = Math.Round((((Math.Round(ri, 2) - 1.0M) * 1000) / (bc)),2);
        dESizeD = dPow(dR1, 2M) - dPow((dia/2), 2M);

        dSizeD = dR1 > dR2S ? Math.Round((dR1 - (decimal)Math.Sqrt((double)dESizeD)),2): Math.Round(dSizeB,2);

        adjthick = Math.Round((dSizeC - dSizeD),2);

        finaloutput = dSizeD > 3.50M ? (float)Math.Round((adjthick + (dSizeD - 3.50M) + 1.50M),2) : (float)Math.Round((adjthick + 1.50M),2);
        return finaloutput;
    }

    public static decimal dPow(decimal x, decimal y)
    {
        Double X = (double)x;
        Double Y = (double)y;
        return (decimal)System.Math.Pow(X, Y);
    }`

However, after hours of trial and error in changing data types, (double, decimal, float etc). I still get discrepancies.

Using these values:

1. sph = -2.00
2. cyl = 0.00
3. ri = 1.74
4. bc = 1.00
5. dia = 75
6. ct = 1.10
7. axs = 180

After executing the stored function in SQL.
I got the result of **4.46**
After running my code in C#.
I got the result of **4.52**

Its a small discrepancy, but as `sph` and `cyl` changes, the difference generated through the two methods also increases.

Question:
Is there a problem within the data types I use?
Does SQL server behaves differently than C#?
Are there other possible factors to these discrepancy?

Comment: There is an easy way to find out where the discrepancy begins.  Simplify both programs down to just run the first computation. Do they give the same results? If no, you're done. You found the difference. If yes, add another line. Repeat until you get a line that gives different results. That's the line with the error.

Comment: @EricLippert I can do that in C# easily but in SQL server is another story.

Comment: This question might also be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152439/what-is-a-good-mapping-of-net-decimal-to-sql-server-decimal

Comment: You might want to check the huge amount of implicit conversions and constants you're using. And doing the math by hand might also help you see where the problem is :)

Comment: @LesH Okay, Ill Check on That.

Comment: Are you running this in a Query window using SQL Server Management Studio, SSDT, or something similar? Add a line after the `END`  -- `SELECT fn_LensThickCalcAC(-2.00, 0.00, 1.74, 1.00, 75, 1.10, 180)` -- which will output the result each time you run the batch. Then you can comment out line by line (SQL Server uses `--` at the beginning of a line for comments).

Comment: @Luaan I've already did it by hand and got the same answer as my C# code. I still wonder why the SQL code differs.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Im running SQL Server Management Studio. I try that too thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as this is not the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.  As a starting point: If your code has more than one if-else statement (or conditional operator), it is probably longer than necessary.  All such statements should be replaced with either their if block or their else block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Got it. I needed to change datatypes of `dia` and `axs` to `SMALLINT` / `Int16` Thank You for the Help