# .Net Decimal precision not matching SQL Server column precision with 0 scale

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a SQL Server table column named ACCOUNT_NO Decimal(13,0). I am using Entity Framework 6.2 Database first approach and I try to insert 1000001231001.0. However, when dbContext.SaveChanges() is called, I get {"Parameter value 1000001231001.0 is out of range."}

I suspect this is because that value would require a Decimal(14,1), however, that column is being used in multiple tables and changing the data type would require a big refactoring that I would like to avoid if possible.

Is there a way entity framework could pass the value without the ".0" at the end?, since I expect integer values all the time.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If the values are always an integer, why not define the value as a `long` in C#? That will (provided you don't have a value greater/smaller than ±9,999,999,999,999) be able to be implicitly cast to a `decimal(13,0)`. Of course, if the value is always an integer, it also seems odd to not have defined the value as a integer data type in SQL Server.

Comment: Even  in .NET `1000001231001m` is not the same thing as `1000001231001.0m` (I mean, they compare equal, but they're different representations). Where are you getting the values from?

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you ought to change the data type in the database. Do you perform maths on account numbers? Account numbers are generally *string of digits*, not numbers, and should generally be stored as strings (with appropriate check constraints). It also means you don't have problems if someone tells you an account number can have a leading `0`.

Comment: [Perhaps useful reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3152535/3181933).

Comment: I agree with all of you in that the column should be defined either as a VARCHAR(13), unfortunately, I am working with a legacy database where the ACCOUNT_NO was defined as Decimal(13,0) and the generated data model mapping kept Decimal as the property Type. I was just wondering if there was a simpler way to tell that as long as the value is x.0 is ok to store it in a Decimal(13,0).

Comment: @JeroenMostert the values are coming from an angular client app without the ".0" but when mapping the value to the data model property the ".0" is added.

Comment: Well that's a problem, then. No, there is no way to get the data layer to accept values with excess precision, even if the digits are all 0 and therefore a conversion would be lossless. T-SQL has all manner of bizarre conversion conventions, but for `decimal` values it's a stickler for the rules. If this is a quirk of EF I don't know how it should be corrected; the model should have the type as `decimal(13,0)` and therefore it should know not to pass values with incorrect precision. Most material I've seen on this applies to Code First only.